# ASP.NET -> Has anyone dealt with image Urls that are over 2500 characters?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, http-post, imageurl

I have ASPX page where I store images. The URL for these images are around 2000 characters.

The value of this URL is read from somewhere and I don't have control.

I would like to know if anyone has handled these type of situation.

I have a javascript procedure that reconstructs this URL.

so I would like to know,

a) How to handle URLs that are longer in length. (I get the URL in OnInit). Since they are longer, I would like to use javascript function that will trim the URL length.

b) Once I get the reconstructed URL (which will be around 500 characters) I want to assign this back to the image and allow the page loading to complete. To achieve

Thanks in advance,

**Update 0 :** I would like to know how httpwebrequest can be used to post an image in the same post??

**Update 1:** I have updated my original post.

**Update 2** Javascript code. This code reconstructions and the submits the document. I am fine with using this javascript as it is OR I can just the modified URL and then assign it to the image in my code-behind (OnInit).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function posturl(url) {
    var qsBegin = url.indexOf("?");
    var qsPattern = new RegExp("[?&]([^=]*)=([^&]*)", "ig");
    var match = qsPattern.exec(url);
    var params = new Array();

    while (match != null) {
        var matchID = match[1];
        if ( matchID.charAt(0) == "&" ) {
            matchID = matchID.substr(1);
        }

        if ( params[match[1]] != null && !(params[match[1]] instanceof Array) ) {
            var subArray = new Array();
            subArray.push(params[match[1]]);
            subArray.push(unescape(match[2]));
            params[match[1]] = subArray;
        } else if ( params[match[1]] != null && params[match[1]] instanceof Array ) {
            params[match[1]].push(unescape(match[2]));
        } else {
            params[match[1]]=unescape(match[2]);
        }   
        match = qsPattern.exec(url);
    }

    var myForm = document.createElement("form");
    myForm.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    myForm.method="post" ;
    myForm.action = url.substring(0,qsBegin) ;
    for (var k in params) {
        var myInput;
        // Check for params with the same name.
        if ( params[k] instanceof Array ) {
            for ( var i=0; i<params[k].length; i++ ) {
                myInput = createFormInput(k, params[k][i]);
                myForm.appendChild(myInput) ;
            }
        } else {
            myInput = createFormInput(k, params[k]);
            myForm.appendChild(myInput);
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
    myForm.submit() ;
    document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
}
```

Comment: URLs in excess of 2000 characters are not well supported, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Since the URL length is an issue, I would like to use a javascript function. I have been not able to get success with the javascript function so far. I will paste that javascript in my original post.

Comment: @SalmanA: I am trying to reconstruct the URL at this point. Getting into some issues.

Comment: Is it (really) a url or the image data (base64) itself?

Comment: @EdSF: Well the URL is longer but I have a javascript routine to reconstruct. Once I get reconstructed URL, I would like to use http post on the image such that is shown when the page is submitted or displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the length of what the protocal can handle, but in the length your client can handle. Most browser have a max get size about 2000 chars. If you want more you need an other browser. However that is normally not under your control.

> The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of a
>   URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they
>   serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they
>   provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server SHOULD
>   return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer than the
>   server can handle (see section 10.4.15).
>
> Note: Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI lengths
>   above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy implementations
>   might not properly support these lengths.

You can try to use a post to send the information to the server and return the image to you client.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I would like to use POST and I need more inputs. CAn you provide the same considering my scenario mentioned above?

Comment: I would like to know how httpwebrequest can be used to post an image in the same post??

Comment: Anyone can suggest me? Don't know if question is very basic? or complex?